# Nagios remote machine error with 'GLIBC_2.8'

Tags: nagios

This is my first question, although I daily read answers here, helps me a great deal. I hope you guys will help me too.

Anyway, here is where I have gotten stuck.
I have Nagios server on Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS \n \l
On one of my remote machines (which is also Ubuntu, but version 8.04.4 LTS \n \l), I did setup of SSH password-less settings (installed keys on both machines, work perfectly). 
But, after adding commands, error is the following:

```
Remote command execution failed: /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk:    
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6: 
version `GLIBC_2.8' not found (required
by /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk)
```

Also here is nrpe. cfg from remote machine:

> command[check_disk_by_ssh]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk -w 20
>   -c 10 -p /dev/sda1

And, here is settings from Nagios:

> Installed libc
>       linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00484000)
>               libc.so.6 => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0x00d8f000)
>               /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x005f3000)

```
        Version information:
        /bin/sh:
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2) => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.11) => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.1.1) => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.0) => /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
        /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6:
                ld-linux.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib/ld-linux.so.2
                ld-linux.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/ld-linux.so.2
                ld-linux.so.2 (GLIBC_2.1) => /lib/ld-linux.so.2
```

Settings of remotelinux machine on Nagios server:

```
 define service{

use                             local-service         ; Name of service template to use

host_name                       remote_linux_machine

service_description             Remote check disk

check_command                   check_disk_by_ssh!check_sda1!20%!10%!/

 contact_groups                  admins
 }
```

And also, commands.cfg:

```
'check_disk_by_ssh' command definition

define command{

 command_name    check_disk_by_ssh

 command_line    $USER1$/check_by_ssh -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -C "$USER1$/check_disk -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$ -p $ARG3$"
            }
```

So, please help me to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at this:

> /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6: version `**GLIBC_2.8' not found** (required
>   by usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk

which says that the version of glibc on your system is not what is required to run on this machine.
so try to remove the nagios plugins and re-install them, which will resolve the dependencies issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up NRPE with `check_by_ssh` plugin.

Comment out the definition of `check_disk_by_ssh` on the Nagios server and edit the `service` definition as belows:

```
define service{
        use                             local-service         
        host_name                       remote_linux_machine
        service_description             Remote check disk
        check_command                   check_nrpe!check_disk_by_ssh
        contact_groups                  admins
        }
```

Reload the `nagios` service and try again.

Comment: No changes. Same error appears, when starting any of commands on remote machine, the following error appear: #/usr/local/nagios/libexec# ./check_ssh -H localhost
./check_ssh: /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.8' not found (required by ./check_ssh)

Comment: Looks like a bug. Did you try to install nagios plugins from Ubuntu repository?

Comment: No, I didn.t. Will try and give you feedback. Thanks again for helping